# Filename created w sprintf truncated when RStudio console width too short

Tags: r, printf, rstudio, truncation

I just encountered something baffling (at least to me) and hope wiser members can shed some light.

I used RStudio 0.98.490 on Windows XP to save a plot to PNG. The filename was created using `strwrap(sprintf())`. I habitually use longer (i.e. more informative) filenames, and I guess I was probably over-enthusiastic this time, which is why this issue surfaced.

I noticed that when the width of the RStudio console is *shorter* than the length of the filename during run-time, the latter gets truncated and the file created does not have the .png extension. I experimented and dragged the width of RStudio console to longer than the filename - the problem disappears.

**My question: why does this happen? More importantly, can I resolve this truncation without changes to my filename? I am a newbie to R and I can't see why 2 seemingly unrelated items should interact.**

Truncation shown below:

```
> writeLines( paste0(FName, " generated") )  # Write to Console
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaabcdef ghijk lmnopqrstuvaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa213424534aaaaaa generated
aaaaaaaaaaaaa.png generated
>
```

Sample code is attached below:

```
astring <- "aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
FName <- strwrap( sprintf("%sabcdef ghijk lmnopqrstuv%s213424534%s.png",
                              astring, astring, astring) )  # simulate long filename
png( filename = FName)

a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)*2
plot(b,a)

dev.off()
writeLines( paste0(FName, " generated") )  # Write to Console
```

The closest resource I found was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104448/preserving-long-comments-in-console-output-not-falling-victim-to-truncat but the problem faced by the author appeared slightly different.

I would appreciate very much if someone can enlighten. Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to @jlhoward, I looked up `strwrap()` and found the width parameter. By assigning '255' (or any big integer), the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `strwrap(...)`?

As the documentation explains, `strwrap(...)` parses your input into words, and then wraps (by inserting `"\n"`) based on a width parameter. The default for this parameter is `getOption("width")`, which is based on the console width. Try typing

```
getOption("width")
```

then shrink or expand your console window and do it again.

If you just use `sprintf(...)` to generate your filename, you don't have this problem.

Comment: Hi @jlhoward, I use `strwrap()` as I also habitually break the `sprintf` text in my _code itself_ for better readability. Assume I use a narrow screen, I would break the code into 2 lines: `FName <- strwrap( sprintf("%sabcdef ghijk` and `lmnopqrstuv%s213424534%s.png",`. The filename would have an unwanted carriage return. Is there a better way to resolve this than `strwrap()`?

Comment: Well, `strwrap(...)` is also inserting an unwanted carriage return, so that's not a solution. I suppose you could use `paste0(...)`, as in: `sprintf(paste0("%sabcdef ghijk",` and `"lmnopqrstuv%s213424534%s.png"),` but the real solution is to avoid such long filenames.

Comment: Point taken, @jlhoward. Thanks!