# twitchr::get_videos gives Internal error in `vec_slice_impl()`: Unexpected `NULL`

Tags: r, dplyr, twitch, twitch-api

I'm trying to get video information by user with get_videos function for twitchr package in R.

The console will give me the following output, when I run it:

```
videos <- get_videos(user_id = 613890167,clean_json = T)

Error: Internal error in `vec_slice_impl()`: Unexpected `NULL`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.



> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Internal error in `vec_slice_impl()`: Unexpected `NULL`.
Backtrace:
1. twitchr::get_videos(user_id = 613890167)
8. dplyr::bind_rows(.)
9. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.




> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Internal error in `vec_slice_impl()`: Unexpected `NULL`.
Backtrace:
     █
  1. ├─twitchr::get_videos(user_id = 613890167)
  2. │ └─twitchr:::make_request(...)
  3. │   └─twitchr:::clean_videos(response_content)
  4. │     └─`%>%`(...)
  5. ├─twitchr:::date_formatter(.)
  6. │ └─`%>%`(...)
  7. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  8. └─dplyr::bind_rows(.)
  9.   └─vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
 10.     └─(function () ...
```

it seems to work with `videos <- get_videos (user_id = 613890167, clean_json = F)`.

So i tried looking for the error inside the **get_videos** function:

```
function (id = NULL, user_id = NULL, game_id = NULL, after = NULL, 
before = NULL, first = NULL, language = NULL, period = NULL, 
sort = NULL, type = NULL, clean_json = TRUE) 
{
 d <- make_request(end_point = "videos", clean_json = clean_json, 
   id = id, user_id = user_id, game_id = game_id, after = after, 
   before = before, first = first, language = language, 
   period = period, sort = sort, type = type) 
 return(d)
}
```

in **make_request**

```
    function (end_point, ..., clean_json = TRUE) 
{
  formatted_params <- format_parameters(...)
  base_url <- "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/"
  url_end_point <- glue::glue("{base_url}{end_point}{formatted_params}")
  response <- httr::GET(url = url_end_point)
  check_status(response)
  response_content <- httr::content(response)
  if (length(response_content$data) == 0) {
    usethis::ui_warn("The request is successful, however, there is no data in the response.")
    return(NULL)
  }
  if (clean_json == TRUE) {
    if (end_point == "bits/cheermotes") {
      result <- clean_bits_cheermotes(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "videos") {
      result <- clean_videos(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "users") {
      result <- clean_users(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "games") {
      result <- clean_games(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "games/top") {
      result <- clean_top_games(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "clips") {
      result <- clean_clips(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "search/channels") {
      result <- clean_search_channels(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "tags/streams") {
      result <- clean_get_all_stream_tags(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "streams/tags") {
      result <- clean_stream_tags(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "search/categories") {
      result <- clean_search_categories(response_content)
    }
    if (end_point == "users/follows") {
      result <- clean_get_follows(response_content)
    }
  }
  else {
    result <- response_content
  }
  return(result)
}
```

in **clean_videos**

```
function (response_content) 
{
  data_clean <- response_content %>% purrr::pluck("data") %>% 
    dplyr::bind_rows() %>% date_formatter()
  return_list <- list(data = data_clean, pagination = response_content$pagination$cursor)
  return(return_list)
}
```

the problem seems to be caused by `dplyr :: bind_rows ()`, indeed:

```
videos <- get_videos(user_id = 238617149,clean_json = F)

xx=videos %>% purrr::pluck("data")

dplyr::bind_rows(xx)

Error: Internal error in `vec_slice_impl()`: Unexpected `NULL`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

`data.table::rbindlist(xx)` instead of `dplyr::bind_rows(xx)` seems to work.

But if I define the function **clean_videos** writing `data.table::rbindlist(xx)` instead of `dplyr::bind_rows(xx)`:

```
clean_videos = function (response_content) 
{
  data_clean <- response_content %>% purrr::pluck("data") %>% 
    data.table::rbindlist() %>% date_formatter()
  return_list <- list(data = data_clean, pagination = response_content$pagination$cursor)
  return(return_list)
}
```

when I try again `videos <- get_videos(user_id = 613890167, clean_json = T)`, the console gives me the same error as output.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647570/5805670 Edit: Or alternatively, the answer below it.

Comment: Using the assignInNamespace function, it works correctly. Thank You.